# About rank of free module compared to spanning and LI set

Tags: modules, free-groups, free-modules

Let M be a free R-module where R is commutative ring with unity.

Q1: If M is FG by n vectors. Will  **rankM** $\leq$ n?

Q2: If M has a LI set $S$. Will #$S \leq$ **rankM**?

What if R is PID?

Are above results true for FG free abelian groups which are free module over Z?

What will be answers in case FG by n vectors, replaced by generated by a set of infinite cardianlity and Q2 also looked for free modules of infinite cardianlity?

Comment: Here is something that might get you started: what is your definition of rank?

Comment: Rank means cardinality of basis. Because M module over commutative ring with unity, it will invariant which can be proved.                                 See definition of basis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module. and commuative ring has IBN property https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number @Hoot

Comment: My point was to look at the proof: you take the isomorphism and you mod out by a maximal ideal and reduce to linear algebra. This kind of strategy easily implies a positive answer to your Q1.

Comment: @Hoot can you please help in proving atleast for case when M is free abelian group over Z